# Overlap2d: How does rendering and loading work?

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, chunks

Hello I started working with Overlap2D and I have some questions how it does work. I'm allso working with libGDX.

1. Does it render the whole map or just the visible part from the player.
2. How does it load the map. Is it possible to load the map in "chunks".

Answer (score 0):

1. Overlap render renders the whole map (scene)
2. Overlap creates json file and loads it to Ashley engine by creating entities from your scene